# How to execute an application using a specific core or cores?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing

I'm writing an application that needs to be executed on a specific core of a processor.
For Example:
If we have 4 cores and i want to execute code on 2nd core only. I need help how to do this.

Comment: Why is it so? What kind of application? What processor? What operating system?

Comment: Operating system is Linux

Comment: That should go into the question, at least as a tag

Comment: And you should explain **why** your application *needs* to be executed on a specific core, and what hardware platform requires that. Most of the time, that is useless and counter-productive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programmer can prescribe his/her own affinities (hard affinities) but use the default scheduler unless a you have a good reason not to.

Here is a C/C++ function to assign a thread to a certain core from Kernel scheduler API:

```c
#include <sched.h>

int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, unsigned int len, unsigned long * mask);
```

It sets the current affinity mask of process `pid` to `*mask`. `len` is the system word size (`sizeof(unsigned int long)`)

To query affinity of a running process:

```bash
$ taskset -p 3935
```

Example output:

```
pid 3935's current affinity mask: f
```

Comment: This is Linux specific. OP did not mention any specific OS in his question

Comment: Yes, I figured it out

Comment: Avoid using pictures in your answer. Use text. An answer with mostly a picture cannot be seeked or googled.

Comment: I flagged this answer as low quality. To improve your answer, put *text* instead of images. So please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55116391/edit) your answer** to improve it. I cannot guess where did you got the *text*

Answer (score 3):

> I'm writing an application that needs to be executed on a specific core of a processor.

This is extremely improbable on most platforms (since most multi-core processors are homogeneous). You really need to explain, motivate and justify such an usual requirement.

**You can't do that** *in general*. And if you could do that, how exactly you should proceed is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific, and platform specific. Most multi-core processors are homogeneous (all the cores are the same), some are not.

On Linux/x86-64, the kernel [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) sees all cores as the same, and will move a task (e.g. a thread of a multi-threaded process) from one core to another at arbitrary moments. Since scheduling is preemptive.

On *some* processors, moving periodically (e.g dozen of times per second) a task from one core to another is actually recommended (and done automagically by the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)), or the firmware - e.g. [SMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode)) to avoid overheating of that core. Read about [dark silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_silicon).

Some unusual hardware (e.g. [ARM big.LITTLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_big.LITTLE)) have two sets of different cores (e.g. 2 high-end ARM cores with 2 low-end ones, all sharing the same memory). If your platform is such, please state that in your question, and ask how to achieve processor affinity on your specific platform. Very likely your OS has appropriate [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) for that purpose.

Some high-end motherboards are [multi-sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket). In such case, a RAM module is closer to one socket (in timing) than to another. You then care about non-uniform memory access.

So read more about [processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) and [non-uniform memory access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access). Most OSes have some support for both. On Linux, see [pthread_setaffinity_np(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html), [sched_setaffinity(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html), [numa(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/numa.7.html) etc...

To learn more about OSes, read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Notice that by pinning some thread to a some fixed core, you might *lower* the performance of your program. Since processor affinity is rarely useful.

Comment: Nice resources +1, virt or iommu users use this sometimes with numa i.e. 'isolcpus=4-7' yet still lot of configuration needed depends on bios, more kernel config (acpi i.e.) and or on qemu

Comment: Very nicely explained 